How to Implement a Custom TensorFlow Layer to Apply CLAHE on an Image?
I am trying to implement a custom TensorFlow layer to apply Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization (CLAHE) on an image. I have written the following code, but I am not sure if it is correct or if there are any improvements that can be made.
Here is my implementation:
def clahe(image, clip_limit=2, tile_grid_size=(8, 8)):
    tiles = tf.image.extract_patches(
        images=tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0),
        sizes=[1, tile_grid_size[0], tile_grid_size[1], 1],
        strides=[1, tile_grid_size[0], tile_grid_size[1], 1],
        rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
        padding='VALID')
    tiles = tf.reshape(tiles, [-1])

    # Calculate the histogram
    histograms = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.histogram_fixed_width(x, [0, 255], nbins=256), tiles, dtype=tf.int32)
    # Clip the histogram
    clipped_histograms = tf.clip_by_value(histograms, 0, clip_limit)
    # Calculate the CDF
    cdf = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.cast(tf.math.cumsum(x) / tf.reduce_sum(x), tf.float32), clipped_histograms, dtype=tf.float32)
    # Map pixel values to the CDF
    equalized_tiles = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.gather(cdf, tf.cast(x, tf.int32)), tiles, dtype=tf.float32)
    # Reshape and resize
    equalized_tiles = tf.reshape(equalized_tiles, [-1, tile_grid_size[0], tile_grid_size[1]])
    equalized_image = tf.image.resize(equalized_tiles, tf.shape(image)[0:2])
    equalized_image = tf.squeeze(equalized_image)

    return equalized_image

class CLAHELayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, clip_limit=2, tile_grid_size=(8, 8), **kwargs):
        super(CLAHELayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.clip_limit = clip_limit
        self.tile_grid_size = tile_grid_size

    def call(self, inputs):
        clahe_fn = lambda image: clahe(image, self.clip_limit, self.tile_grid_size)
        return tf.map_fn(clahe_fn, inputs, dtype=tf.float32)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({'clip_limit': self.clip_limit,
                       'tile_grid_size': self.tile_grid_size})
        return config

img_path = 'test_img.jpg'
img = Image.open(img_path)
img = img.resize((256, 128))
img_array = np.array(img) / 255.0
img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
predictions = model.predict(img_array)
predictions = np.squeeze(predictions, axis=0)
clahe_img = Image.fromarray(predictions.astype(np.uint8))

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('Original Image')
plt.axis('off')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(predictions)
plt.title('Clahe Image')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

I have a few questions regarding this implementation:

Is the clahe function correctly implemented for applying CLAHE to an image using TensorFlow?
Is the way I am using tf.map_fn appropriate for applying the CLAHE function to each image in a batch?
Are there any potential issues with the way I am saving and loading the model with the custom layer?
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you!


Hello. Welcome to your community! Your post is good, but programming questions are generally off-topic. You could try to ask your question e.g. on Data Science SE or Stack Overflow. We focus on the AI theory, philosophy and social aspects. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.
